# Is there a way to get heap analytics data using APIs? I only see POST APIs in their API documentation

Tags: heap-analytics

Is there a way to get heap analytics data using APIs?  I only see POST APIs. I only see APIs documentation to post data in their API documentation.

Referring to this document:
https://docs.heap.io/reference

Tried A LOT to find but could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate Heap Analytics data, you need to use https://help.heap.io/heap-connect/heap-connect-guide/heap-connect-guide-overview/